# Use Laravel Livewire Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I'm new to Laravel-Livewire (current v3).
By default it ships with a nice modal (for debugging).

As it's already there I'd rather re-use it than install another package / write my own.
Couldn't find anything in the docs..

How can I use the default modal in my project?

Comment: I know nothing of this. Maybe you’ve seen some packages that rely on Livewire

Comment: Livewire does not ship with any default UI preset or anything like it. Maybe you're thinking of the Alpine.JS UI components (which there are similar for Livewire)? But they are not free, or come standard with Livewire.